# Can a AirCanada travel voucher be used on a partner airline? Example United Airlines

Tags: bookings

Air Canada flight to Dominican Republic from Newark airport was cancel and was offered a Travel voucher.  Checking possible later date to rebook flights no direct flights or a days travel example earliest arrival after 6 pm?  Is it possible I could book a flight from a partner airline? Example United Airlines

Comment: From the comments below: "Air Canada doesn't fly from Newark to the Dominican Republic" How was that ticket booked, who was operating the flight (United ?) and who issued a voucher for what ?

Answer (score -1):

The voucher typically comes with terms and conditions. These will spell out the specific rules: how long, what for, how to use it, etc. Without reading the rules it's hard to tell but most likely the answer is "no".

> Air Canada flight to Dominican Republic from Newark airport was cancel and was offered a Travel voucher.

You should NOT have accepted the voucher but insisted on a full refund. In most cases airlines are required to give you full refund. In most cases the airlines will offer travel credit or a voucher instead. That's bad for you but good for the airline, so you should NOT accept it.

Once you accept the voucher, it's difficult to get your money back.

Comment: "That's bad for you but good for the airline" Travel vouchers are intentionally worth more than the cash refund. It's an overgeneralization to say it's bad for you, it requires careful consideration. Admittedly, it would be difficult for OP to look up flights at the gate when offered.

Comment: How is a travel voucher for $100 worth more than $100 in cash? It's a different story if the voucher is for more than the original price, but that's quite rare in my experience. Every time I was offered a voucher, it was just for the original price.

Comment: Air Canada does not operate direct flights between Newark and the Dominican Republic.  Can you clarify if this was codeshare or a flight with connections?

Comment: @Hilmar good luck getting a refund with Air Canada…

Comment: @ZeroTheHero: AC's terms and condition clearly state that you can opt for a refund in terms of cancellation. However, the devil is in the details. Good catch on the code share (or whatever that is).

Comment: @Hilmar technically you may be entitled to a refund but AC (and in all fairness most Canadian airlines) make the process impractical by forcing you to interact with their remote system (no point in using the call center, where hold times are extremely long anyways), denying legitimate claims, and by being otherwise completely obstructionists in their interactions.  Things may be a little better if you have status but the whole refund promise is basically a scam.